# How do I fill a textbox with text if it is empty?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I use a `TextChanged-EventHandler`
I wrote a program in c# that creates a new `TextBox` on every `button1_Click` event
Now,I want each new `TextBox` (which was created) to show typed text.
How can I do this with EventHandler(TextChanged)?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Int32 i = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox c = new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(c);
        c.Name = "x" + i.ToString();
        c.Left = 3;
        c.Top = 30 * i;
        i++;
        c.TextChanged += new EventHandler(c_TextChanged);


    }

    void c_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text =           
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correct. Did you mean, that every time you input text, all textboxes should show these input?

Comment: Not All of them,Only the first TextBox
That
There is on the form!

Comment: Ok, then Clemens/Herms answer should help you ;-), pls accept one answer to mark problem as solved, if it works for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void c_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the sender of your object should be the textbox. There you can get the text you want:

```
void c_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox box = sender as TextBox;
    if (box != null)
    {
        textBox1.Text = box.Text;
    }
}
```